# json data not displaying results as expected

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "userid": "1831",
    "authorname": "WhatsApp",
    "message": "There are only two times that I want to be with you: Now and Forever.",
    "likes": "2",
    "type": "romantic",
    "yourlikes": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "userid": "1831",
    "authorname": "WhatsApp",
    "message": "My six word love story: “I can’t imagine life without you.”",
    "likes": "1",
    "type": "romantic",
    "yourlikes": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "userid": "1831",
    "authorname": "WhatsApp",
    "message": "You have no idea how much my heart races when I see you.",
    "likes": "3",
    "type": "romantic",
    "yourlikes": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "userid": "1831",
    "authorname": "WhatsApp",
    "message": "Since the time I’ve met you, I cry a little less, laugh a little harder and smile all the more, just because I have you, my life is a better place.",
    "likes": "0",
    "type": "romantic",
    "yourlikes": "0"
  }
]
```

You can see the following:

```
"yourlikes": "1"
```

When I display it by message it is `0`

*CODE*

```
public class ShowMessages extends AppCompatActivity {

    String type;
    ArrayList<Item_Messages> item_messages = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rv_message;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_messages);




        Intent intent = getIntent();
        type = intent.getStringExtra("type");




        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Information.URL_Messages + Information.userid + "&type=" + type, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for(int x = 0 ; x < response.length() ; x++)
                    {
                        item_messages.add(new Item_Messages(response.getJSONObject(x).getString("id"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("userid"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("authorname"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("message"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("likes"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("type"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("yourlikes")));
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(ShowMessages.this, "" + response.getJSONObject(2).getString("yourlikes"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                rv_message = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_message);
                rv_message.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShowMessages.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                Adapter_Messages adapterview = new Adapter_Messages(ShowMessages.this, item_messages);
                rv_message.setAdapter(adapterview);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



    }
}
```

custom array list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Item_Messages {


    String id,userid,authorname,message,likes,type,yourlikes;


    public Item_Messages(String id, String userid, String authorname, String message, String likes, String type, String yourlikes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.authorname = authorname;
        this.message = message;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.type = type;
        this.yourlikes = yourlikes;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it shows `0` and not `1` in the result?
I have searched a lot and did not find anything related to this issue Could the problem be in the `php` files? All data displays correctly, except:

```
"yourlikes": "1"
or
"yourlikes": "0"
```

Please can you try and help me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `Toast.makeText(ShowMessages.this, "" + item_messages.get(2).yourlikes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: not worked , any idea :)

Comment: if its just a toast try to insert it inside for loop then try to get the current position of your "yourlikes" 
                     `Toast.makeText(ShowMessages.this, "" + response.getJSONObject(x).getString("yourlikes"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I already did , not worked

Comment: @zain can you please post also your output? I don't see any problem to your code. Or did you verify the `yourlikes` value of your json if it is 0 or 1?

Comment: I know there is no problem but when I print yourlike he tells me everything 0 I dont know why

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code, could you print the return json or just hard code the json first to make sure it's not the coding problem?